# Can I let clients construct DB Queries for my Django Server, and remain secure?

Tags: python, ajax, django, database, security

So, first up, a Gist (incase text below is not clear) - https://gist.github.com/chozabu/86b60caa0ce211f232da

basically, it seems fairly simple to let any client pass a few dicts to my server (for filters, excludes and sorts) and have loads of my API *done* with a tiny amount of code that also supports future complex queries I have not thought of!

A client can ask for `posts that have tax X but not tag Y within a date range and a rating greater than Z` or nearly anything else (except statistical aggregation).
A query dict can look like:
`{
'filters : [{ post__stats__score__gte : 0.3 }],
'sort_by' : 'post__author__created_at' '
}`

My concern is that a client could abuse this, to filter for only people with a certain email, pw-hash or, again, something I have not thought of.

Think it is practical to make something like this secure, with careful use of black/white-listing? And perhaps altering the query serverside to exclude any data a client should not be viewing?

FWIW, My current plan is to build a system with django-rest-framework, adding something like this as an extra option only if needed, and I can find a way to make it secure.

Comment: It's not very clear what you want and what your concern is. Allowing users to send certain data to your server which would  be persisted in your database? Why don't you do it through API endpoints so you can sanitise data and make sure no malicious code reaches your db. Also, you can create restricted users that have only access to certain query types or certain tables. If you'd store the user provided filters, etc. in a separate table, then you should create a db user that can access only that table.

Comment: Right now I am looking at read-only access to my database - the crux being *allowing clients to construct their own queries* to save writing large amounts of server-side code, and let clients create custom, very complex queries

Comment: Apart from security concerns, this is also a UI concern. How exactly are you planning to implement this? Building an elaborate UI and utilizing ORM are good practices.

Comment: I've actually already implemented this in a hobby project, check out http://voteflow.net/agora/ and click "filters" - UI was just quickly chucked together with jquery. I think making a nice UI with Anuglar will not be a problem - really, my only concern is security!

Comment: I've used one project before, it blocks all db writes and make your db readonly. https://github.com/streeter/django-db-readonly

Comment: I must have explained myself worse than I thought, though django-db-readonly also looks handy, what I am talking about is letting a client (such as angularJS frontend) construct dicts that are used by Djangos ORM, for the args passed to its filter, exclude, sort and limit methods!

Comment: Django restricted the use of filters in the Django admin in 1.2.4 ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.2.4/#restricted-filters-in-admin-interface)) to prevent users from being able to return sensitive information like password hashes. Be careful not to cause the same problem. You might want to create a whitelist in a similar way.

Comment: Nice link Alasdair! That is about the exact kinda info I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of DRFs filtering page: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/
There are some 3rd party extensions like

- https://github.com/miki725/django-url-filter
- https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters

which seem to be extensions to fix this exact need (I'm amazed neither in core DRF!)

edit: Alasdair commented above, about similar functionality being removed from django-admin in version 1.2.4, and use of a whitelist to ensure security

So, I guess the answer to my original question is really "Yes, as long as you know what you are doing, and are careful - probably using a whitelist rather than a blacklist"